# OpenGL. После применения матриц (MVP) треугольник неправильно отображается

Tags: c++, opengl

Попробовал добавить в программу, которая рисует треугольник, матрицы, с помощью которых можно было бы легко перемещать треугольник. Теперь треугольник неправильно отображается: во первых не по центру, и сам он немного повёрнут. Что не так?

Попробовал использовать команду `glViewport`, но это ничего не поменяло.

```
#include <iostream>

#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <SDL.h>

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#define WINDOW_WIDTH 800
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 600

int main()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_STENCIL_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("OpenGL Draw", 100, 100, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    float vertices[] = {
        0.0f, 0.5f, // Vertex 1 (X, Y)
        0.5f, -0.5f, // Vertex 2 (X, Y)
        -0.5f, -0.5f // Vertex 3 (X, Y)
    };
    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    const char* vertexSource = R"glsl(
        #version 150 core
        in vec2 position;
        uniform mat4 mvp;
        void main()
        {
            gl_Position = mvp * vec4(position, 1.0, 1.0);
        }
    )glsl";
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    const char* fragmentSource = R"glsl(
        #version 150 core
        out vec4 outColor;
        void main()
        {
            outColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        }
    )glsl";
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);

    glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)WINDOW_WIDTH / (float)WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(0, 0, 5),
        glm::vec3(1, 1, 1),
        glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)
    );
    glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 mvp = Projection * View * Model;
    GLuint matrixId = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mvp");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixId, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvp[0][0]);
    SDL_Event windowEvent;
    while (true)
    {
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&windowEvent))
        {
            if (windowEvent.type == SDL_QUIT) break;
        }
        else
        {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        }
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
    }
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: треугольник]

Comment: `glm::vec3(1, 1, 1)` поменяйте на `glm::vec3(0, 0, 0)` чтобы смотреть в центр

Comment: @user7860670 сработало. Но почему, если поставить позицию в mvp * vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); и glm::vec3(1, 1, 1), то треугольник не виден? Ведь камера смотрит на позицию треугольника ...

Comment: `если поставить позицию в mvp * vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);` - непонятно...

Comment: mvp::model — это "Identity Matrix". Я имею ввиду в шейдере, если изменить позицию треугольника на 1, 1, 1 и указать камеру на эту сторону, то треугольник не виден.

Comment: Ээ, нет. Если в шейдере заменить `mvp * vec4(position, 1.0, 1.0);` на `mvp * vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);`, то все вершины окажутся в одной точке.

Comment: @user7860670 точно, спасибо, я что-то немного подзабыл, как работать с графикой :) Скорее всего это из-за того, что брался за OpenGL после DirectX

Comment: @user7860670 ещё я не понимаю почему после вызова `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);` треугольник мигает как старый телевизор и потом нормально отображается. Если эту функцию поместить до цикла while (true), то она вообще вечно будет мигать.

Comment: Потому что `SDL_GL_SwapWindow` вызывается, даже если на этой итерации цикла ничего не рисовалось.